# Android - create group by wifi direct p2p for multiple devices

Tags: android, p2p, wifi-direct

I want to create a group for multiple devices by wifi direct p2p protocol in a specific manner. I want to gather data from other devices to one device. I should make the receiver device, the group owner. for example by clicking a button, it should create a group and send out a broadcast to others so that they join the group automatically. (I know that the device should accept the connection at first, but I assume that we don't need it.)

I've searched a lot, but I can't find any clue. I appreciate any advice or comment on my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, there is no broadcasts available with the API.

instead, you use the createGroup to form a group, then create local service, and then make sure the peerDiscovery is on (I'm rather sure the device and the local service is only visible to others when the API is active)

In others simply do Peer/Service discovery and connect once you find what you are looking for.

You could also workaround the dialog, I explained two ways in my [blog](http://www.drjukka.com/blog/wordpress/?p=39).

Comment: @dr-jukka thank you for your answer, I have another question though. For this kind of connection, do the devices need to connect to a specific access point or their wifi only should be on?

Comment: Basically, if you want to use the Normal Wifi-Direct, then you don't use access points, you just use the API and the functionality it offers.

Comment: But, if you use the Access point created, then you would need to get the password for the access point delivered to the connecting side. Check other articles on my blog for more info.

Comment: but in my case , I want to create a group without using any other access point, I want to use this application outdoor where there is no access point. 

now I create a service with one of devices, but the other one can not see the service, each device can see only its own service. It seems both of them need to be connected to an access point to get an IP

Comment: I'm not following what you are descriping. The Wifi Direct indeed is mean to make connections between devices, and its not requiring any addiitonal IIP settings or accesspoints. So you coculd maybe try out my samples and see what they do.

Comment: It sounds like Alireza should be broadcasting his service and connection details using the Wifi Direct NSD API. Then he can create a group, and the others should be able to figure out the connection details from the Wifi Direct service broadcast (which should not require an access on point). The one place this might break down though is on legacy devices which don't support the Wifi Direct natively. In this case though, I could imagine embedding the connection details in the access point name, or transmitting that info with Bluetooth.

Comment: @Dr.Jukka: Have you tried using your Application [MyWifiMesh] on some Samsung devices like S7 Edge, A5 etc. Because I observe that on these devices, it gives the SSID and password, but no device can connect to it. Looks like some dummy SSID and password is provided by the API which the legacy devices cannot connect.

Comment: I want to create the group when the device is connected to another access point. so when i call createGroup does this disconnect the device from already connected Access point